# AngularJS Http Post causing numbers to datetime conversion

Tags: angularjs, post

AngularJS Http Post causing numbers to date time

We have simple

```
$http.post(URL, data);
```

Also tried

```
$http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: "/URL/",
         data: dataField,
         headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
         }}).then(function(result) {
             console.log(result);
         }, function(error) {
             console.log(error);
         });
```

wherein data is a json object as below:

```
{
   name: 'Test',
   orderno: '19801212'
   date: '20170101'
}
```

$http post is converting the orderno field to a date time format while sending it to web api.  This is unintended use as we deserialize the json as an object on c# webapi side.  On looking through the actual client side request, we noticed that $http post is doing this internally.

Do you know a way to avoid the automatic conversion of string field to datetime?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use: **'Content-Type': 'application/json'**

```
$http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: "/URL/",
         data: dataField,
         headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         }}).then(function(result) {
             console.log(result);
         }, function(error) {
             console.log(error);
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code was culprit-

```
angular.module('app').config(["$httpProvider", function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse.push(function (responseData) {
        convertDateStringsToDates(responseData);
        return responseData;
    });
}]);


var regexIso8601 = /^([\+-]?\d{4}(?!\d{2}\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\3([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\d|[12]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|6[1-6])))([T\s]((([01]\d|2[0-3])((:?)[0-5]\d)?|24\:?00)([\.,]\d+(?!:))?)?(\17[0-5]\d([\.,]\d+)?)?([zZ]|([\+-])([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)?)?)?)?$/

function convertDateStringsToDates(input) {
    // Ignore things that aren't objects.
    if (typeof input !== "object") return input;

    for (var key in input) {
        if (!input.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

        var value = input[key];
        var match;
        // Check for string properties which look like dates.
        if (typeof value === "string" && (match = value.match(regexIso8601))) {
            var milliseconds = Date.parse(match[0])
            if (!isNaN(milliseconds)) {
                input[key] = new Date(milliseconds);
            }
        } else if (typeof value === "object") {
            // Recurse into object
            convertDateStringsToDates(value);
        }
    }
}
;
```